# Email Forwarding Proxy / Gmail

Tags: email, proxy, gmail, forwarding

We currently have an issue where we're not receiving mails from a vendor due to them having a low SBRS (senderbase reputation score) and our corporate mail thus blocking messages from them.

To work around this issue I'm hoping to give the vendor a proxy address (e.g. my personal gmail details), and setup a rule such that it will forward on mails from that domain to anyone with an @myCompany.com address copied (To/CC) on the original mail.  As such we can continue to communicate using our corporate accounts, but by copying in my gmail account work around the blockage.

Looking online I've found how to forward all emails, but no tips on something more subtle/complex as defined above.

Ideal rule would be something like this.

- Mail Received
- If mail.from.domain == @vendorCompany.com then

  - to = mail.to.foreach(recipient => if(recipient.domain == @myCompany.com) return recipient)
  - cc = mail.cc.foreach(recipient => if(recipient.domain == @myCompany.com) return recipient)
  - mail.forward(to, cc)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ps. here's what I've read so far; but it doesn't seem as dynamic as I'd require (i.e. to amend who it forwards to based on who was copied on the original): http://www.tomjepson.co.uk/how-to-auto-forward-specific-emails-in-gmail/

Comment: As a businessperson, you ought to KNOW how idiotic it is for you to hand out your "personal gmail details".  But if you don't understand this or think you are just smart enough to ignore common sense, please feel free to email me your social security and driver's license numbers.  Or, you can be a teeny bit smarter and suggest that the sender open his OWN gmail account when he wants to send you gmail or, better, get their issue fixed.

Comment: @Debra: FYI: I'm not putting my email out for all to see (though to be honest most could probably guess it), only giving it to a couple of people I've been working with already (who seem reasonable people I'd happily go for a pint with) and people who work with me (who are reasonable people I've happily gone for a pint with).   Also, it's only the address, not my password.  With regards to people at work knowing my personal mail; I don't do anything I'm ashamed of online, so don't need to worry about my email being googled.